# Can I rename my "Recyle Bin" folder in WinXP?

Tags: windows-xp, rename, recycle-bin

I want to rename my "Recycle Bin" folder on my Windows XP system so that it's like the "Trash Can" of my Ubuntu's.

I cannot find a simple "Rename" command on right-clicking.

I might have to head over to the registry editor. I'm just not sure. I need the entire process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [simple registry editing](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000543.htm):

> - Click Start and then Run
> - Type regedit and press enter.
> - Open the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT folder.
> - Open the CLSID folder.
> - Open the {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E} folder.
> - Open the ShellFolder folder.
> - Change the Attributes data value from 40 01 00 20 to 50 01 00 20.
> - Once completed change the CallForAttributes dword value to 0x00000000 (double-click and change value data to 0). You must change
>     both of these values to get the rename to appear.
>
> After performing the above steps you can rename the icon like any other icon. Right-click the Recycle Bin icon on the desktop and click Rename and rename it to whatever you want.